# Django migrations: local variable 'field' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

When trying to make migrations in Django I get the following error. Can any help me understand what the problem is and how it possibly can be solved?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/john/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "/home/john/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/john/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/john/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/john/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 150, in handle
    loader.project_state(),
File "/home/john/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 323, in project_state
    return self.graph.make_state(nodes=nodes, at_end=at_end, real_apps=list(self.unmigrated_apps))
File "/home/john/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 409, in make_state
    project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)
File "/home/john/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 92, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
File "/home/john/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 289, in state_forwards
    delay = not field.is_relation
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'field' referenced before assignment
```

I'm using Django 1.11.1 and Python 3.5.

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: Just added version to question: Django 1.11.1

Comment: paste views.py code snippet??

Comment: Any specific part of views.py? I have multiple views split into separate files.

Comment: I think this more of an issue with your models. But also, this seems to be an issue with Django itself. In the current master in their git repo, the `state_forwards` method has been massively refactored compared to the `1.11.x` branch.

Comment: OK, good to know. I'm gonna try downgrading to 1.10 and see if that helps.

Comment: Downgrading to 1.10.7 solved the issue for me.